# Apache rewrite rules issue

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Below are the contents of my apache conf files. I am expecting the following behavior:-

- http://www.mywebsite/google -> www.google.com  (Working)
- http://www.mywebsite/somecode/google -> www.yahoo.com (Not working).

Could someone give feedback on what i am doing wrong. As far as i understand RewriteRule is context aware and these should work as expected.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/mylocalhost"
    ServerName www.mywebsite

    # Other directives here
    RewriteEngine   on
    RewriteRule ^/google$   http://www.google.com/ [R]  
</VirtualHost>

Alias /somecode "C:/somecodedir/"

<Directory "C:/somecodedir/">
    RewriteEngine   on
    RewriteRule ^/google$   http://www.yahoo.com/ [R]

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: If you remove the `/` from `^/google` in that second one (`^google`), does that help?

Comment: No, that doesnt work.

Comment: .. it should... enable your logging to see what it does (see also the link I gave in the answer about `^/` not matching anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `/` in `^/google` (=> `^google`).

[*"The removed prefix always ends with a slash, meaning the matching occurs against a string which never has a leading slash. Therefore, a Pattern with ^/ never matches in per-directory context."*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)